# Auto formatting all drive in windows

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, virus

I want to make a bat file in windows when double click on that
it will delete all existing partion even C drive from the computer.

Means it will make the hardisk Empty.
Plz suggest me process.
How to do this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.dban.org/ has a tool to nuke all drives.

A script to do so can be misused...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete or format the system and boot partitions from a running Windows. All other partitions can be deleted or formatted using `diskpart` with a script, e.g.:

```
C:\>type script.txt
select volume 3
delete volume
exit
C:\>diskpart /s script.txt
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: FOOBAR

Volume 3 is the selected volume.

DiskPart successfully deleted the volume.

Leaving DiskPart...
```